# Use immutable.ListMap in place of mutable.LinkedHashMap

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to use immutable data structure as much as possible.
Very general case in our code base is use of *mutable.LinkedHashMap*. I want to replace this with *immutable.ListMap* in all non-performance critical code.

General format that our code is having like

1. mutable.LinkedHashMap initialization
2. loop condition
3. based on some condition add element in LinkedHashMap
4. After loop, return LinkedHashMap

Sample Code:

```
def dummyFunction(): mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int, String] = {
    val tmpListMap: mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int, String] = mutable.LinkedHashMap()
    for (i <- 1 to 10) {
        if (i%2 ==0) tmpListMap += (i -> "even")
        else tmpListMap += (i -> "odd")
    }
    tmpListMap
}
```

I want to use ListMap in all such places. I don't want to loop again tmpListMap to create ListMap.

Scala Version: 2.11

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Retuning mutable data structure from any method is concern for me. I am trying to limit the scope of "mutability" of variables

Comment: Yes, sounds good! What's the question?

Comment: @Dima I want to change method signature to def dummyFunction(): immutable.ListMap[Int, String]. It will be great if I can done away with mutable.LinkedHashMap altogether. I have seen magical YIELD on for loop that returns immutable collection in scala

Comment: Yes, you can yield from a loop. You can return immutable collections.

Comment: IMHO, this question would not help you. It is great that you do not want to use mutability, intention is the very first step ;). But I doubt this very simple and probably unrelated to your real code example will help. Sometimes it is not _easy_ to be immutable, specially when refactoring code that was already designed around mutability. And if you are stuck on this very basic example, then I believe you will face problems with real code. I think it would be better if you share a more realistic example. Also, it would be good if you share why do you need a `ListMap` it is quite strange col.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am not refactoring existing code. I am writing new code, but keep on using LinkedHashMap and retuning same.

Comment: @user811602 Ok, then Dima's greatly well explained advices will be of great help.

Comment: ListMaps are incredibly inperformant. I'd recommend using a Linkedhashmap for construction and returning the collection.Map interface to whatever uses it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't know how to return an immutable map, because you cannot modify it after it is created? Is that the question? 
Many ways. For example:

```
(1 to 10).map { 
    case x if x%2 == 0 => (x -> "even")
    case x => (x -> "odd")
 }.toMap
```

The above returns a regular `Map`, not `ListMap`. I am not sure why you want the latter, but, if you do for some reason, it is a little more involved:

```
 val tuples = (1 to 10).map { 
    case x if x%2 == 0 => (x -> "even")
    case x => (x -> "odd")
 }
 ListMap(tuples:_*)
```

Yes, you can also yield from a for-comprehension (I am not sure why you would want to in this case), like this:

```
val tuples = for {
  x <- 1 to 10 
  kind = if (x %2 == 0) "even" else "odd"
} yield (x -> kind)
```

This does the same thing as the `map` call above.

You can also start with `ListMap` to begin with to avoid conversion at the end:

```
 ListMap((1 to 10).map(_ -> ""):_*).map { 
   case (k, _) if k%2 == 0 => k -> "even"
   case (k, _) => k -> "odd"
 }
```

Or just:

```
 ListMap(
    (1 to 10).map {
       case x if x%2 == 0 => x -> "even"
       case x => x -> "odd"
     }:_*
 )
```

There is also `.foldLeft`, that lets you write it in a way that most resembles what you currently have in the sense, that it gradually accumulates the changes in the map rather than doing a single conversion at the end ... not sure why you would want that though, it is the least efficient way:

```
 (1 to 10).foldLeft(ListMap.empty[Int, String]) { 
    case (x, map) if x%2 == 0 => map.updated(x, "even")
    case (x, map) => map.updated(x, "odd")
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Dima, you are right that i didn't know how to return ListMap from yield. But I know :)